# React Adding Image in accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a FAQ page and I am having below three files:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import FAQ from './FAQ';

function App () {
  const [faqs, setfaqs] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      question: 'This is question 1?',
      answer: 'This is answer 1',
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: 'This is question 2?',
      answer: 'This is answer 2',
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: 'This is question 3?',
      answer: 'This is answer 3',
      image: 'Question3.png',
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: 'This is question 4?',
      answer: 'This is answer 4',
      open: false
    }
  ]);

  const toggleFAQ = index => {
    setfaqs(faqs.map((faq, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        faq.open = !faq.open
      } else {
        faq.open = false;
      }

      return faq;
    }))
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="faqs">
        {faqs.map((faq, i) => (
          <FAQ faq={faq} index={i} key={faq.id} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`FAQ.js`

```
import React from 'react'
function FAQ ({faq, index, toggleFAQ}) {

    // console.log(faq.hasOwnProperty('url'));

     if(faq.hasOwnProperty('url') && faq.hasOwnProperty('image')){
         console.log("Hello URL");
         return (
            <div
                className={"faq " + (faq.open ? 'open' : '')}
                key={faq.id}
                onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}
            >
                <div>
                    <div className="faq-question">
                        {faq.question}
                    </div>
                    <div className="faq-answer">
                        {faq.answer}
                        <div className="faq-url">
                            <a href={faq.url}>Link to URL</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="faq-image">
                            <img src={`/src/media/${faq.image}`} alt="Image for FAQ"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
         )
     }
     else {
        console.log("No url");
        return (
            <div
                className={"faq " + (faq.open ? 'open' : '')}
                key={faq.id}
                onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}
            >
                <div>
                    <div className="faq-question">
                        {faq.question}
                    </div>
                    <div className="faq-answer">
                        {faq.answer}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         )
     }
    }

export default FAQ;
```

`Index.css`

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:#4caf50;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3c3c3c;
}

header h1 {
    color: rgb(26, 25, 25);
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.faqs {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

.faqs .faq {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5 ;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.faqs .faq:hover {
    background-color: #f0ebeb;
}

.faqs .faq .faq-question {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 80px;

    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.faqs .faq .faq-question::after {
    content: '\2B9B';
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.faqs .faq .faq-answer {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.faqs .faq.open .faq-question {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.faqs .faq.open .faq-question::after {
    /* transform: translateY(-70%) rotate(180deg); */
    content: "\2B99";
}

.faqs .faq.open .faq-answer {
    max-height: 1000px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Directory structure of all the pages are like below:

[image]

App.js consist of state of objects containing various question and answers for FAQ page. Also it consist of FAQToggle which checks if Accordion is open or not and closes the accordion if it is open and vice versa.

FAQ.js Line:24(Actual issue which I am facing): I am trying to add an image so that answer 3 can hold the image. But all I can see is a broken image icon. Can anyone help me in debugging this?

Comment: I think you might need to import the image into the js file and use it as a variable. Place the image name into your state array and target it with your img src tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only use photos in your components if you import then first, let me know if im wrong. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

This post says you "need" to import them first: https://www.edwardbeazer.com/importing-images-with-react/

Heres another: https://daveceddia.com/react-image-tag/

Quote - "A common mistake for beginners is to set the src to a file path on their computer, like /Users/yourname/Projects/this-react-app/src/image.png. That won’t work."

Quote - "Browsers are mostly sandboxed these days and won’t let you access files by their path on disk. If you did get that to work (maybe with file://), it’d break as soon as you deployed the app, because a web server won’t have that file in the same place! (And no, the solution is not to put it in the same place on the server"

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import FAQ from './FAQ';
import Question3 from "./media/Question3.png" //import img here

function App () {
  const [faqs, setfaqs] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      question: 'This is question 1?',
      answer: 'This is answer 1',
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: 'This is question 2?',
      answer: 'This is answer 2',
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: 'This is question 3?',
      answer: 'This is answer 3',
      image: Question3, // use it as a variable
      open: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: 'This is question 4?',
      answer: 'This is answer 4',
      open: false
    }
  ]);

  const toggleFAQ = index => {
    setfaqs(faqs.map((faq, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        faq.open = !faq.open
      } else {
        faq.open = false;
      }

      return faq;
    }))
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="faqs">
        {faqs.map((faq, i) => (
          <FAQ faq={faq} index={i} key={faq.id} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
     if(faq.hasOwnProperty('url') && faq.hasOwnProperty('image')){
         console.log("Hello URL");
         return (
            <div
                className={"faq " + (faq.open ? 'open' : '')}
                key={faq.id}
                onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}
            >
                <div>
                    <div className="faq-question">
                        {faq.question}
                    </div>
                    <div className="faq-answer">
                        {faq.answer}
                        <div className="faq-url">
                            <a href={faq.url}>Link to URL</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="faq-image">
                            <img src={faq.image} alt="Image for FAQ"/> //target it here
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I have tried importing image in `FAQ.js` file but it didn't quite worked for me. But the solution you provided solved my issue I was facing.. Thanks a lot it worked like charm... :-)